# Bound on roots of a monic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a real monic polynomial of degree $n$. The following information is given about $p(x)=0$:

1. all roots are real
2. there is no zero root
3. exactly $k$ roots are positive and $n-k$ roots are negative, $k>n/2$.
4. sum of the roots is $1$ and Product of the roots is $P$.

I am looking for some good bounds (and/or references) on the maximum and minimum root.

Comment: In Feddeev's Problems in higher algebra Exercises 686-692 have many bound for the roots. 690 should  be particularly interesting for you: For $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$, with $a_k$ real, no real root exceeds $\rho+\sqrt[r]{\max\left|\frac{a_k}{P\rho^{k-r}}\right|}$, where $\rho$ is any positive number, $r$ is the index of the first negative coefficient ($n-1$ in your case) and $k$ ranges over the indexes of the negative coefficients. Applying the result to $f(-x)$ you can get a lower bound for the negative roots.